# Why is this sum what it is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation

I am trying to prove that

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1+2} + \frac{1}{1+2+3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1+2+3+\cdots+n} = \frac{2n}{n+1}$$

I know the denominators have a closed form $\sum_{i=1}^{k} i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ implying

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1+2} + \frac{1}{1+2+3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1+2+3+\cdots+n} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

Can't figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know how to write a proof by induction?

Comment: @mweiss Sort of. Prove a base case and then prove an incremental case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Notice that : $$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}.$$

Comment: I had tried this too, but the sum of harmonic numbers has no closed form, so I didn't continue this approach.

Comment: Using this trick you get a teslescoping sum.

Comment: So (1/1 - 1/2) + (1/2 - 1/3) + (1/3 - 1/4) + ... + (1/n-1/(n+1)) means everything but the first and last terms cancel out to (1-1/(n+1)) so 2(1-1/(n+1)) = 2n/(n+1), nice! I didn't even notice that. How did you see that it was telescoping?

Comment: Tricks of the trade.  Telescoping is a very common trick (that's how we know 1+....+n = n(n+1)/2). So we tried to force a telescope and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To continue sheol's answer.

A telescope sum cancel out.

$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 2( \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}))$

$= 2(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k + 1})$

$= 2(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k + 1})$

$= 2(\frac 1{0 + 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k + 1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k + 1} + \frac 1{n+1})$

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do a straight proof using induction and your formula $\sum_{i=1}^{k} i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

Just add  $\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{2n}{n+1}$